# Why does it suffice to check the geodesic equation to leading order?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I am reading [Taubes's book on differential geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199605874) and am wondering about a proof. My apologies if this is simple, as I'm still grappling with the material. My question concerns material in chapter 8, page 83.

Embed $S^n$ into $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ as the set of points with $|x|=1$. Pulling back the standard metric on $\mathbb R$ gives a metric on $S^n$ called the round metric. Taubes asserts the geodesic equation for a curve $\gamma: \mathbb R \rightarrow S^n \subset\mathbb R^{n+1}$ with coordinates $(x^i(t))$ is given by
$$\ddot x^j + x^j|\dot x|^2=0.$$

To show this, he introduces the map $y\rightarrow (y, (1-|y|^2)^{1/2})$ from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R$ that embeds the ball of radius $1$ into $S^n$. Pulling back the round metric gives 
$$g_{ij} = \delta_{ij} + y_i y_j(1-|y|^2)^{-1}.$$
(This expression fixes a typo found in the book and pointed out [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197295/what-is-the-geodesic-equation-on-mathbbsn))

Expanding in a power series and writing out the geodesic equation gives 
$$\ddot y+y_j|\dot y|^2 +O(|y|^2)=0.$$

Taubes asserts that since this matches the original equation to leading order in $y$, the claim is proved. Why is this? That is, why does it suffices to check that the equations agree to leading order?
His justification, which I do not understand, is:

> This agrees with what is written above to leading order in y. Since the metric and the sphere are invariant under rotations of
>   $S^n$, as is the equation for $x$ above, this verifies the equation at
>   all points.

Presumably the second sentence is just referring to the face that, by symmetry, it suffices to verify the equation for the given coordinate patch, but perhaps there is more I am missing.

I am also confused because the equation in $y$ is in $\mathbb R^n$, but the equation in $x$ is in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. What is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frankly, I don't understand this type of arguments, they look to me as if taken from a 19th century treatise. I think that the stupid but straightforward approach is best here, and not really difficult.

Assuming that the geodesic equation is $\ddot x ^i (t) + \sum \limits _{j, k}\Gamma ^i _{jk} \dot x ^j (t) \dot x ^k (t) = 0$ and that $\Gamma ^i _{jk} = \frac 1 2 \sum \limits _a g^{ia} ( g_{aj, k} + g_{ak,j} - g_{jk,a} )$ (the comma means "covariant derivative", which for functions is exactly the partial derivative in local coordinates), then the first thing to do would be to compute $g_{ab,c} = \frac {\partial g_ {ab}} {\partial y_c} = \partial _c \space g_{ab} $. This gives

$$\partial _c g_{ab} = \frac {(\delta _{ac} y_b + \delta_{bc} y_a) (1-|y|^2) + 2 y_a y_b y_c} {(1-|y|^2)^2}$$

so that

$$g_{aj, k} + g_{ak,j} - g_{jk,a} = 2 \frac {y_a} {1-|y|^2} g_{jk} .$$

Now, let us compute the inverse matrix of $(g_{ij}) _{i,j}$. The following computations will be done formally, ignoring convergence issues since in the end the results will turn out to be valid. If we let $M = \Big( \frac {y_i y_j} {1-|y|^2} \Big) _{i,j}$, then we must invert $I + M$, the formal inverse of which is $\sum \limits _{p \ge 0} (-1)^p M^p$. Note that $M^2 = \frac {|y|^2} {1-|y|^2} M$, so that $M^p = \Big( \frac {|y|^2} {(1-|y|^2)} \Big) ^{p-1} M$ for $p \ge 1$. Then, our formal inverse becomes $I + \sum \limits _{p \ge 1} (-1)^p \Big( \frac {|y|^2} {(1-|y|^2)} \Big) ^{p-1} M = I - (1-|y|^2) M$. Remarkably, this inverse is not just a formal inverse, but a true matrix inverse, as you can check by yourself by multiplying with $I+M$. Thus, this gives $g^{ia} = \delta ^{ia} - y^i y^a$.

Plugging the above into our calculations, we get

$$\Gamma ^i _{jk} = \frac 1 2 \sum \limits _a (\delta ^{ia} - y^i y^a) 2 \frac {y_a} {1-|y|^2} g_{jk} = y^i g_{jk} (y) ,$$

so the equation of the geodesics becomes

$$0 = \ddot x ^i (t) + \sum \limits _{j, k} x ^i (t) g_{jk} \big( x(t) \big) \dot x ^j (t) \dot x ^k (t) = \ddot x ^i (t) + | \dot x (t) |^2 x ^i (t) .$$

One final note: the coordinates $x^i (t)$ of $x(t)$ are coordinates on $S^n$, not in $\Bbb R ^{n+1}$! I mean, $x^i (t) = y^i (x(t))$ where $(y^1, \dots , y^n)$ are local coordinates on $S^n$.

PS: The reason why the formal inverse computed above turns out to be a valid matrix inverse is essentially the following: the expression of $(I + M)^{-1}$ is an analytic function of $y^1, \dots, y^n$; it is true that its Taylor series around $0$ is convergent only in some ball around $0$, but its closed-form expression stays valid on a larger domain.

Comment: Just to be clear, the equation you derive in local coordinates has $n$ variables, which will imply (with the extra condition $|x|=1$) the $n+1$ variable version Taubes gives in ambient $\mathbb R^n$ space, right?

Comment: @Potato: No. :) These computations are "intrinsic", i.e. they do not require any ambient space. If $t \mapsto x(t)$ is your geodesic (sitting inside the upper half-sphere without the equator, denoted $S^n _+$) and $h = f^{-1} = (h^1, \dots, h^n) : S^n _+ \to B(0,1) \subset \Bbb R ^n$ is the local chart that we work in (with $B(0,1) = \{ y \in \Bbb R ^n | |y| < 1\}$ and $f$ as in the question that you link to), then $x^i (t) = (h^i \circ x) (t)$. If you really want to emebed things in $\Bbb R ^{n+1}$ you must add a new last coordinate given by $\sqrt {1 - |x|^2}$. But this is not needed here.

Comment: The equation Taubes is trying to prove involves the $n+1$ coordinates in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, controlling the $n+1$ components $\gamma^i$ of $\gamma$. This is why I'm confused! In local coordinates, we get the same answer he does, but surely using that screwy last coordinate to put things in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ is going to give a weird answer and break the symmetry, right?

Comment: @Potato: Exactly. In fact, that equation is valid *only* in local coordinates, it does not even exist in "ambient" coordinates.

Comment: Then is the book printing it with $n+1$ coordinates instead of $n$ just another typo? It seems clear from the book that the equation Taubes is trying to prove is in the $n+1$ coordinates of the path in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. In fact this is how he derives the geodesics.

Comment: It also seems that there should be *some* nice equation in $n+1$ variables of ambient $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ space that controls the geodesics. Can't you take this one and perform a change of variables to get such an equation, and perhaps use symmetry and so on to simplify it?

Comment: @Potato: Ha! Taubes' claim is blatantly false: you can see in the proof above that $\ddot x ^1 + x^1 |\dot {\bar x}|^2 = 0$ (I'm using $\bar x = (x^1, \dots, x^n)$, i.e. just the first coordinates). What Taubes says is that the correct equation is $\ddot x ^1 + x^1 |\dot x|^2 = 0$ (without bar on $x$). But $|\dot x|^2 = |\dot {\bar x}|^2 + (\dot x ^{n+1})^2$ and this last term changes everything. Taubes' version and mine cannot be simultaneously true, and since mine is...

Comment: I see! I am now unconfused. Thank you. These typos are driving me nuts.

Comment: @Potato: I am afraid that this is more severe than a typo: the author makes a mistake and keeps repeating it during the whole example 8.4.2. He mixes notations, this is what he does. I also strongly dislike the fonts used in the book: usually, authors use the "standard" LaTeX fonts for mathematical publications. This book, however, looks as if it has been written in MS Word... May I suggest using another book? If not, contact the author with questions (I have done this myself and authors are usually friendly and communicative). Direct him to this page.

Comment: I have in fact already jumped ship to Lee's Introduction to Curvature. However, this example still nagged at me. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Potato: To end this discussion: if curvature is what interest you (as opposed to differential or Riemanian geometry in general), you might find [this](http://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/PDF/1[77].pdf) conference by Gromov very rich. (Mind you, this is not a textbook to learn after!)

Answer (score 2):

The geodesic equation is, loosely speaking, of the form $\ddot y+f(y)\dot y\dot y=0$.
In particular, all terms contain derivatives of $y$.
By this structural knowledge, we know that if we have a geodesic equation $\ddot y_j+y_j|\dot y|^2+O(|y|^2)=0$ where the $O(|y|^2)$ term contains no $\dot y$ or $\ddot y$, then the $O(|y|^2)$ must actually vanish.
This could of course be concluded by doing the calculation in detail, but it is not necessary; in this case we know that the rest of the terms have to add up to zero.
It is of course a good check for one's calculations to actually see that zero is what you get.

If you just had two ODEs like that, you could not conclude that they had the same solutions.
The argument that it suffices to throw away everything without derivatives works with geodesics because they have a special equation.
I find it weird that such an argument is not explained when used in a book.

Another problem is that $x$ has $n+1$ coordinates and $y$ has $n$.
The $x$-coordinates are constrained by $|x|^2=1$ and the $y$-coordinates are free, so both have $n$ dimensions at disposal.
We can assume that we are working in a patch where $x^{n+1}>0$, so we aim to identify $x^j=y^j$.
These satisfy the same equation as observed.
The thing that remains to check is that $|x|$ remains 1, using the equation for $x$.

Comment: Interesting! I'm still wondering how the passage to the $x$-coordinates works. I'm thinking it should be enough, roughly, to establish that in the ambient $\mathbb R^n$ space the equation has the form $\ddot x + f(x)\dot x \dot x=0$, then note that the projections given won't change most of the derivatives, so you can compare the nonlinear coefficient $f(x)$ with the known coefficient $f(y)$ and equate them to get the answer. Does this seem to be on the right track?

Comment: @Potato, you have $x^j=y^j$ for all $1\leq j\leq n$, right? The coordinates are the same, other than $x$ also having the $(n+1)$st coordinate but $y$ not. You can always assume that you are working in an open set where $x^{n+1}>0$ since the sphere doesn't care about rotations. Of course you can make a more elaborate change of coordinates, and the result will be the same, but I think (but don't really know) the point in the book was that these two equations are actually the same.

Comment: Yes, $x^i=y^i$ for $i\le j \le n$. (Sorry -- that's what I meant when I said the projections won't change most of the derivatives.) I suppose my confusion stems partly from the fact that a system of $(n+1)$ equations in $x$ is seen to be equivalent to a system of $n$ equations in $y$ (by deleting all appearances of $x^{n+1}$?), but perhaps this is not surprising because we have the additional constraint that $|x|^2=1$.

Comment: @Potato, yes, you just have to check that the $n+1$ equations for $x$ preserve the condition $|x|^2=1$. This implies that it is enough that $x$ and $y$ agree on the first $n$ coordinates. It does indeed require an argument that the $(n+1)$-dimensional system for $x$ is equivalent with the $n$-dimensional one for $y$, and this point was missing from my answer. (I think I will complement it in a moment.)